# Android app shows screen before LoginActivity

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am making an Android app with authentication. The startup activity is MainActivity, but when a user is not logged in I start a new activity called LoginActivity.

My problem is that if a user is not logged in and starts the app, he see's a default android app screen (title bar and empty content area) for a split second before the LoginActivity launches.

How can I fix this?

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(!userIsLoggedIn())
        {
            Intent LoginActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            LoginActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(LoginActivity);
            finish();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You should probably reverse the order that they load.  So load the login screen first, with a message saying "redirecting" if they are logged in.

Comment: Does your userIsLoggedIn() function work correctly ?
In my opinion your if statement is false and you have not set setContentView(R.layout.main) so it will be blank

Comment: This is just an example, I am only creating the login activity for now. userIsLoggedIn() always returns false

Comment: If I reverse the order then I will get the same problem if the user **is** logged in.

Comment: So long as your not calling setContentView, I don't see why anything would be displayed?

Comment: The content isn't displayed before setContentView but the app does start an "empty activity" where the content gets loaded into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your MainActivity translucent by setting the activity theme `android:style/Theme.Translucent`. Which makes the activity transparent so you won't see any thing till other activity starts.

But this has drawbacks. The animation that accours when you click to the application icon, you won't see that anymore and If your `userIsLoggedIn()` takes more than it should, it will look like the phone is froze for a second to the user.

Comment: Thanks! My userIsLoggedIn() takes almost no time at all so it works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

For such situations, best practice is to have a splash screen activity or welcome screen activity appear as first screen for few seconds (1 or 2 sec). This screen is generally contains your company logo/image, like Facebook app. In this activity you put the logic to decide which activity to call next.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            if(alreadyLoggedIn)
              startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
            else
              startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,LoginActivity.class));

    finish();
    }
}, 1000);
```